# ASP.NET MVC - How to model bind query string parameters in application start just like action method of controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to ask if it's possible to model bind querystring parameter in application start up just like in controller's action method? is there any attribute class I can use to make this happen? example:

```
public ActionResult myMethod(MyModel modelName){
    return View(modelName);
}
```

Comment: Why would the application have access to *any* querystring on startup?

Comment: Short answer: **No**

Comment: thanks for the response. I just my thought if it's possible so i can get the model on start of post/get request and use it globally around the application.

Answer (score 0):

in MVC the application start-up defined in RouteConfig :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Welcome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

if you want to manipulate param use the id property.